# Undefined reference to "function"

Tags: c, reference, undefined

So I have this very simple program but I can't seem to get rid of a simple error.

I have a Header file with this

```
    #ifndef FUNCTIONLOOKUP_H_INCLUDED
    #define FUNCTIONLOOKUP_H_INCLUDED


    enum functions
    {
      foo,
      bar
    };

   //predefined function list
   int lookUpFunction(enum functions);

   #endif // FUNCTIONLOOKUP_H_INCLUDED
```

And in the src file i have the definition of lookUpFunction

Now when I call the lookUpFunction() from my main where I included the header file it gives me a undefined reference to it. The other awnsered questions where of no help.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include "FunctionLookUp.h"

   int main()
   {
     lookUpFunction(foo);  <---
     return 0;
   }
```

Function implementation

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "FunctionLookUp.h"

    typedef void (*FunctionCallback)(int);
    FunctionCallback functionList[] = {&foo, &bar};

   void foo(int i)
   {
     printf("foo: %d", i);
   }

   void bar(int i)
   {
     printf("bar: %d", i);
   }

   int lookUpFunction(enum functions)
   {
     int test = 2;

    //check if function ID is valid
    if( functions >= sizeof(functionList))
    {
       printf("Invalid function id"); // error handling
       return 0;
    }

    //call function
    functionList[functions](test);
    return 1;
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out where this error comes from.

Comment: You need to link with `FunctionLookup.o`, or add `FunctionLookup.c` to the compiler invocation.

Comment: Don't define `false`, `true` on your own. Modern C is supposed to provide them in the header `stdbool.h`. And if (but please don't unless you have real reasons) define them the other way round such that it comes naturally in C, namely that `0` is false and a non-zero value is true. Here you have `true == 0` and `false == 1`.

Comment: Daniel Fischer: I am using codeblocks as editor and never had this problem before while i made a dozen of these programs. How is it i suddenly have to change things

Jens Gustedt: I know already deleted it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must have some file similar to:

```
/* FunctionLookUp.c */
#include "FunctionLookUp.h"

int lookUpFunction(enum functions)
{
  /* code ... */
  return x;
}
```

somewhere in order to solve your problem

Comment: i have, i will paste it in as well since this could be unclear

Comment: All seems correct to me (after see your edit), if you want to get more help show your Makefile or tell us how do you invoke gcc plus the complete error message

Comment: Codeblocks generates the make file, yeah thats why this is bugging me so much

Comment: @flexzican ops, then I can't help you, are you compiling in the right path?

Comment: yes, i just threw all my code in 1 file and this works. So thats not it. o ok thanks for your time anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You never show code that *implements* the function.

So it's most likely that what you're seeing is a linker error, the call itself is fine but the linker cannot find the code to call, so it throws an error.

Just declaring a function can't magically make it appear from somewhere, you must write the actual function too.

Comment: Like i said, i have it written in FunctionLookUp.c the code in there works.